# Big amount of onclick elements...or perhaps some jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm building an app that at a certain point generates a pretty big summary table (20x~200). Some of the cells(probably 1000), which I can identify in the backing code, need to have some sort of onclick bind. The value of those cells needs to be parsed to a inputfield on the page.

I've investigated the inline rendering of: onclick=genericfunctioncall("copy_of_celldata")
Somehow this isn't feeling modern enough for me.....:)

Since I'm using JQuery for some other stuff I would like to make use of it. Thought about class binding and id binding(must make me render ID's, and enormous amounts of binds).
Class binding is my prefered way. But because I render the table dynamically (Ajax calling a partialview in MVC4 and rendering the .data) I have to use the .on("click",....) method. 
I can't figure out a way to detect which TD I clicked to determine it's value and parse that to the input.

Someone an idea?

Comment: Within your click handler, `this` is the element that was clicked. You can then traverse the DOM to find other elements relative to the event target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a common class to all the `td` you want to assign the click event on.

Use **event delegation** as you are binding the same for more than 1000 elements.

Use `this` context inside the event to get the td on which the event was triggered.

```
$('table').on('click', '.tdClass', function() {
     // this refers to td which triggered the event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been very pleased with using jQuery.data(). You can bind anything you want to a DOM element.  If you have a JSON response from your server here would be an example of using that:

```
$.get('/url',function(resp){
   $.each(resp,function(k,v){
       // v is json object {"name":"item name","id": 22, "link": "http://www.google.com"}
       var item = $('<li />');
       item.html(v.name);
       item.data('item',v);  //attach your json object to dom element.

       $('ul').append(item);
   });
});
$('ul').on('click','li',function(){
      var data = $(this).data('item') // get your original object 
      alert(data.link) -->> "http://www.google.com"
      // do whatever you need to do.
});
```

Comment: I do have JSON capabilities on my server. I do use it to populate an .autocomplete input. But I believe, I want to stay as close to the MVC model as possible. So, for rendering tables and such I prefer using Partialviews using MVC4. Works great.